# Kubernetes. namespaces isolation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

Previously, to restrict access between namespaces i used:

```
net.alpha.kubernetes.io/network-isolation: "on"
```

In version 1.6.1 does not work. 
The currently proposed version:

```
net.beta.kubernetes.io/network-policy: |
  {
    "ingress": {
      "isolation": "DefaultDeny"
    }
  }
```

The currently proposed version is not satisfied, because you need to create separate policies for the pods.

Is there something like this now?

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the doc([Declaring Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/declare-network-policy/)) which specifies how you can apply the network policies, I tried all that in a minikube cluster, only to realize that the network provider should also support the `NetworkPolicy`.

This [introductory doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/declare-network-policy/) says that `NetworkPolicy` is supported in Calico, Weave, Romana.

This [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/) has detailed information of what all providers support `NetworkPolicy`.

Answer (score 0):

Which network provider do you use in your cluster? Network provider you use should support the `NetworkPolicy`. NetworkPolicy controller must be setup in your cluster. If there is no NetworkPolicy controller running in your cluster, `NetworkPolicy` will not work.